# I am using proxy model, Seller(CustomUser) and Customer(CustomUser), I am getting 'SellerManager' object has no attribute 'normalize_email' error

Tags: django, django-admin

Error occurs when I create `class CustomUser` by subclassing **AbstractUser** , but I don't get error when Create `class Customuser` by sublassing **AbstractBaseUser**. Why?

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    # making default username to none instead using email as username field
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'),unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    """
    Multiple user type without extra fields
    # 1. Boolean Select Field
    # option to make if user is seller or customer
    is_customer = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_seller = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    # 2 Choice Field with djnago multiselect
    # type = (
        # (1, 'Seller'), 
        # (2, 'Customer')
    # )
    # to select one of two choice, to select multi instal package django-multiselectfield
    # user_type = models.IntegerField(choices=type, default=1)

    # 3 Separate class for different rolles and many to many field in user model
    # usertype = models.ManyToManyField(UserType)

    """
    # Multiple user with extra field
    # 1 boolean field with class for different role
    # is_customer = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    # is_seller = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    # Proxy model
    class Types(models.TextChoices):
        CUSTOMER = "Customer", "CUSTOMER"
        SELLER = "Seller","SELLER"
    
    default_type = Types.CUSTOMER
    type = models.CharField(_('Type'),max_length=255, choices=Types.choices, default=default_type)

    # if not code below then taking default value in user model not in proxy in model
    # The point is that we do not know what arguments save is expecting so this is 
    # basically saying "any arguments passed into our new save(...) method,
    # just hand them off to the old overridden save(...) method,
    # positional arguments first followed by any keyword arguments"
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.type = self.default_type
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']

    # specify all objects for the class comes from
    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Hello @VikramChoudhary please provide your **SellerManager**

Comment: I got the solution, problem arises when I make CustomUser with sublassing AbstractUser. When I sublass ABstractBaseUser problem disappears. Can you explain that?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem arises because probably your  CustomUserManager is not inheriting those predefined function from UserManager.

Make sure, that your CustomUserManager inherit all the required function for AbstractUser operations.

Like,

```
class CustomUserManager(UserManager):
     .....
```